CKEditor 5 " Cannot Upload File : [Filename] " in Laravel 11
I want to upload an image to Ckeditor, but when I upload it to the text editor, I can't
 public function upload(Request $request)
    {
       if ($request->hasFile('upload')) {
            $originName = $request->file('upload')->getClientOriginalName();
            $fileName = pathinfo($originName, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $extension = $request->file('upload')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fileName = $fileName . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension;

            $request->file('upload')->move(public_path('media'), $fileName);

            $url = asset('media/' . $fileName);
            return response()->json(['fileName' => $fileName, 'uploaded'=> 1, 'url' => $url]);
        }
    }

<script>
        ClassicEditor
            .create(document.querySelector('#body'), {
                ckfinder: {
                    uploadUrl: "{{ route('ckeditor.upload', ['_token' => csrf_token()]) }}",
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    </script>

Route::post('ckeditor/upload', [ProfileController::class, 'upload'])->name('ckeditor.upload');

I want the images I upload to appear in the blog details

This might answer your query, check the link--> https://stackoverflow.com/a/74560588/21210375

Please use this code instead of your script tag.
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace('description', {
        filebrowserUploadUrl: "{{ route('ckeditor.upload', ['_token' => csrf_token()]) }}",
        filebrowserUploadMethod: 'form'
    });
</script>

and use this callback for response:
$url = asset('images/'.$fileName);
$msg = 'Image successfully uploaded' . 'the URL is :' . $url;    
$response = "<script>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction($CKEditorFuncNum, '$url', '$msg')</script>";
    
 @header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
 echo $response;

